# Vue 3 yarn serve stuck at 42% when importing external js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Vue 3 `yarn serve` stuck at 42% when I try to import an external js file into main.ts.

This is what causes the issue:

**main.ts**

```
import '@/assets/js/jquery.min.js';
```

No error just stuck at:

> 42% building 267/276 modules 9 active
> /Users/mark/Documents/workspace/testapp/test-web/node_modules/html-entities/lib/surrogate-pairs.js

When I try to import **any** external js file I have the same issue.

As there is no error output as such, can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put the jquery javascript file in that folder?
Try to add the dependence using package.json and import it like this example
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

I see that you're using typescript because of your main.ts file and usually the app cannot compile js files when you are using typescript in your project

Comment: Thank you for the responce. Correct in that I'm using typescript and the external files are normal js. So when using typescript is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for the help you comment helped me find the issue. Indeed, by using a package it now works.